# How do I redefine a z3 formula in the current context?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am trying to check for equivalence of two formulas f1, f2 using z3py.

```
def check_sat(*args):
    s = Solver()
    for v in args:
        s.add(v)
    return s.check()


def check_equiv(f1, f2):
    # a, b = Ints('a b')
    # f1 = Not(a == b)
    # f2 = Not(b == a)
    if check_sat(f1, Not(f2)) == unsat:
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

Now this works fine if I uncomment the code inside check_equiv but not working if f1 and f2 are
passed as parameters. Here f1 and f2 are coming from two different sources, however, they are using the same global context.

Is there any way to circumvent the problem considering the sources cannot be changed. I was wondering if there is any way to redefine the formulas f1, f2 inside the function check_equiv.

Comment: You should provide an example of what is *not* working. i.e., what sort of error message you're getting and a minimal example to recreate it. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```py
from z3 import *

def check_equiv(f1, f2):
    if f1.ctx != f2.ctx:
        raise RuntimeError("Invalid Context mix!")
    if (f1.sort_kind() != Z3_BOOL_SORT) or \
       (f1.sort_kind() != Z3_BOOL_SORT):
        raise RuntimeError("Bool expressions expected!")
    s = Solver(solver=None, ctx=f1.ctx)
    s.add(Xor(f1, f2))
    return s.check() == unsat

ctx1 = Context()

i = Int('i', ctx1)
j = Int('j', ctx1)

f1 = i == j
f2 = j == i

if check_equiv(f1, f2):
    print(f"equivalent! {f1} == {f2}")
else:
    print(f"not equivalent! {f1} != {f2}")
```

The Solver Context is taken from the first formula expression.

Both expressions have to be of sort Bool. For arithmetic expressions, a different equivalence check would be required.

I used `Xor()` to include the case `And(Not(f1), f2)`.